# Start IE with no Add-Ons

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I'm looking for a possibility to start a IE with no Add-Ons with my code.
The following code works fine, but starts a normal IE.

How can I start a IE with no Add-Ons with my code?

Thank you in advance!

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass();
object missing = new object();
ie.Navigate(url, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start IE without any add-on by utilizing System.Diagnostics.Process.  Sample below.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process ieProcess;
ieProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "-extoff");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "http://stackoverflow.com" + " -extoff");
```

also possible to have several options

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "http://bullion.ru" + " -extoff -private");
```